# How can I develop a strategy for serving 45 second videos to hundreds of thousands of users?

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-hosting

I am closing up development on a web site that allows people to watch thousands of videos which are on average 45 seconds in length.

I'll be hosting the web application on Linode, but I'm unsure whether I should use Linode, a cloud file service or a custom server + T1 for serving the videos.

Can anyone offer guidance here?

Thanks,

Comment: A T1 (if we're talking about the same T1) is going to be woefully inadequate for this job.

Comment: If you want a custom server, drop it in a colo, you'll need a lot more pipe than a T1. I'd say depends on the scale, if it's a start-up project, go cloud till your income (and demand) matches getting dedicated hardware.

Comment: T1 isn't going to cut it. Still, a 45-second really crappy-quality video is an entirely different beast than a 45-second HD video. Get a CDN, or an all-in-one service... nimbushd.com (shameless plug ;)

Answer (score 2):

A hosted streaming service, maybe even using a CDN, seems like a good idea here: http://www.streamzillacdn.com/. A [Google search for "hosted streaming plan"](http://www.google.com/#q=hosted+streaming+plan) would bring up more providers, if necessary.